# Open Chat Window on Button Click

Tags: html, css

I have implemented Live Chat button in my HTML website like below

```
<div id="ds-sticky-button"> <a href="#"><strong>LIVE CHAT</strong></a></div>
```

Its working fine but pure chat have given me code for open chat window is like below

```
<button type="button" class="purechat-button-expand">Chat with us!</button>
```

If I use this code its changing button design which I do not want. Can anyone please suggest me how can I open chat window with my First code?

Thanks

Comment: define the click event that has defined in pure chat button to your chat button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you wrap the anchor inside a div. this is not necessary, if you use CSS to make your anchor display:block;

To answer your question, you need to recreate the example’s styling...
If you are calling the styles from them, then ideally you’d just use the same HTML as the example, but you could try just using the same id reference that they use, ie. #ds-sticky-button.
If that doesn’t work, it’s because they refer to it more specifically in their css.
If you’re not including styling attributes or CSS file from the example, you need to inspect what styles are making their example look the way it does, using something like Chrome dev tools (or firebug in Firefox), and recreate them.